# How to use variables extracted from json extractor into headers and JSR223 sampler

Tags: jmeter

We need to use two variables extracted from JSON response,one need to corelate in Header and other into JSR223 preprocessor of another sampler .

How can we implement the same using JSON extractor??

Please assist with example.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you need to extract two variables from Json response, Is this your question?

Comment: Yes.I need to extract two variables from which one is to pass in Next sampler's header and other is to next sampler's JSR223 preprocessor.

Comment: Is it possible to paste the JSON, You Can use Json extractor at the Sampler level to extract data and can it to different samplers or headers using the variables defined

Comment: I tried but no luck.Can you please illustrate with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have JSON response like:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

You can extract the 2 values into 2 JMeter Variables using the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as follows:

[image]

Once done you can access the variable in form of `${variable_name_here}` in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and as [`vars.get('variable_name_here')`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) in the JSR223 PreProcessor

[image]